# How do I display the number of total responders to a poll?

Tags: php, ajax, survey

I have a poll which I made using PHP and Ajax, the poll is a yes/no question, and my code only shows the % of yes and no. The big question is: how I display the number of total responders. In following, Ii will display the code I use:

```
<script>
function getVote(int) {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_app/poll_vote.php?vote="+int,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<h3 align="center">Are you satisfied with our services?</h3><br>
<form id="pollform">
yes:
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="0" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
<br>no:
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="1" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
</form>
</div>
```

The php code:

```
$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];
//get content of textfile
$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);

//put content in array
$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

if ($vote == 0) {
  $yes = $yes + 1;
}
if ($vote == 1) {
  $no = $no + 1;
}

//insert votes to txt file
$insertvote = $yes."||".$no;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fputs($fp,$insertvote);
fclose($fp);
?>

<h2>Result:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Yes:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll1.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>No:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll2.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You have the values ($yes and $no), so just modify the code in the response to display those values. $yes + $no = total votes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have both total answers in you text file. You can simply show both individual responses with percentage (%) and total responses below to them. Just like below in html code you can write something:

```
<h2>Result:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Yes:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll1.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
(<?php echo $yes;  ?> Vote) </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>No:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll2.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
  : (<?php echo $no;  ?> Vote)   </td>
</tr>
<tr> <?php echo $yes+$no; ?> total responses. </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 @summit-sharma, but the next question is, how do i limit the number of votes by only one for users IP?

Comment: @AndresConstantin In your case as you are saving votes in text file, just add user's IP address with them like   **$yes . "||" . $no . "||" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];**
But if this is not good practice to handle all this without database it can make problem if the users are so many that will going to vote.
Thanks